# which firmware boots up when we turn on the power?

Tags: operating-system, processor, firmware

All I know is It helps in initializing processor hardware and operating system.
First I need to know what is a firmware and how it works. 
Probably showing a list of firmware and what they do can be a good idea for explanation.

Comment: I checked what is BIOS, but its different from a firmware, what I want here is the firmware that is responsible to initialize the processor hardware

Comment: The term "firmware" has evolved to refer to any program code (and sometimes even data) that is stored in nonvolatile memory (e.g. ROM, PROM, EEPROM and flash).

Comment: Power-on or boot is initiated with a hardware reset of the processor.  This reset loads a predetermined address into the `Program Counter` aka PC register.  The computer would be designed/built so that nonvolatile memory (e.g. ferrite core memory, ROM, PROM or flash) existed at that reset/restart address.  The size of this boot memory dictates its capabilities, and often simply leads to loading a larger, more capable program.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, microprocessors performa  start up process that usually takes the form of "begin execution of the code that is found starting at a specific address" or "look for a multibyte code at a pinpointed location and jump to the indicated locale to begin execution"

Since the introduction of IC ROM, with its many variants, including, but not limited to mask programmed ROMs, and programmable ROMs, and EPROMs. Since this time, firmware boot programs were shipped and isntalled on computers. Then the introduction of an external ROM was an italian telephone switching elaborator, called "Gruppi Speciali".

When a computer's turned off, it's software remains stored on nonvolatile data devices such as HDDs CDs DVDs SD cards, USBs, floppies, etc. WHen the computer's powere don, it doen't have an operating system or its lloader in RAM, it first of all executes a relatively small program stored in ROM, along with a small amount of needed data to access the nonvolatile device or devices from which the operating system programs the data and can be uploaded into RAM, this small program being known as a bootstrap loader.